# Sort JSON in alphabetical order - Flutter

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I'd like to be able to return my profileList to my ListView in alphabetical order.

I have my "All people" class which has a ListView widget using the json and creating a list of people.

The code below is from my All People class where I'm fetching the json.

```
class AllPeople extends StatefulWidget {
final String title;

AllPeople(this.title);

@override
AllPeopleState createState() => AllPeopleState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("Listviews"),
),
);
}

class AllPeopleState extends State<AllPeople> {
 List data;
 List<Profile> profiles;

 Future<String> getData() async {
 var response = await http.get(
    Uri.encodeFull("http://test.mallcomm.co.uk/json_feeds/users.json"),
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

  fetchPeople().then((List<Profile> p) {
    this.setState(() {
    data = json.decode(response.body);
    profiles = p;
  });
});

return "Success!";
}

@override
void initState() {
  this.getData();
}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('CMS Users'),
  ),
  body: ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 4.0),
      itemExtent: 70.0,
      itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          elevation: 10.0,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        new PeopleDetails("Profile Page", profiles[index]),
                  ));
            },
            child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                child: Text(profiles[index].getInitials()),
                backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                radius: 30.0,
              ),
              title: Text(
                  data[index]["firstname"] + "." + data[index]["lastname"]),
              subtitle: Text(
                  data[index]["email"] + "\n" + data[index]["phonenumber"]),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
  );
  }
 }

Future<List<Profile>> fetchPeople() async {
 try {
 http.Response response =
    await http.get('http://test.mallcomm.co.uk/json_feeds/users.json');

 List<dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

 List<Profile> profileList =
    responseJson.map((d) => new Profile.fromJson(d)).toList();

profileList.sort((a, b) {
  return a.lastName.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.lastName.toLowerCase());
});

  return profileList;
} catch (e) {
print(e.toString());
}
return null;
}
```

I then have my "User profile" class which is storing my json Profile

```
class Profile {
 final String firstName;
 final String lastName;
 final String phoneNumber;
 final String userEmail;

bool verifiedValue = false;
bool approvedValue = false;
bool securityApprovedValue = false;
bool blockedValue = false;

Profile({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.phoneNumber, this.userEmail});

factory Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return new Profile(
  firstName: json["firstname"],
  lastName: json["lastname"],
  phoneNumber: json["phonenumber"],
  userEmail: json["email"],
  );
 }
```

I've tried to do something like

```
 profileList.sort((a,b) {
return a.lastName.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.lastName.toLowerCase());
 });
```

just before I return profileList but it didn't work. I've tried looking at some different examples but If i'm honest I don't understand it too well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sort function you suggested does seem to work as you'd expect (but, of course, only compares last name - you might want to compare first name if the last names are equal). I tidied up a bit, to produce this working example:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main() async {
  fetchPeople().then((list) {
    list.forEach(print);
  });
}

Future<List<Profile>> fetchPeople() async {
  try {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get('http://test.mallcomm.co.uk/json_feeds/users.json');

    List<dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Profile> profileList =
        responseJson.map((d) => new Profile.fromJson(d)).toList();

    profileList.sort((a, b) {
      return a.lastName.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.lastName.toLowerCase());
    });

    return profileList;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}

class Profile {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final String userEmail;

  bool verifiedValue = false;
  bool approvedValue = false;
  bool securityApprovedValue = false;
  bool blockedValue = false;

  Profile({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.phoneNumber, this.userEmail});

  factory Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Profile(
      firstName: json["firstname"],
      lastName: json["lastname"],
      phoneNumber: json["phonenumber"],
      userEmail: json["email"],
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Profile: $firstName $lastName';
  }
}
```

Here's a `State` example that works.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Profile> profiles = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _refresh();
  }

  void _refresh() {
    fetchPeople().then((list) {
      setState(() {
        profiles = list;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<List<Profile>> fetchPeople() async {
    try {
      http.Response response =
      await http.get('http://test.mallcomm.co.uk/json_feeds/users.json');

      List<dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

      List<Profile> profileList =
      responseJson.map((d) => new Profile.fromJson(d)).toList();

      profileList.sort((a, b) {
        return a.lastName.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.lastName.toLowerCase());
      });

      return profileList;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return [];
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => new Text('${profiles[i].firstName} ${profiles[i].lastName}'),
        itemCount: profiles.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I've tried to apply the solution however it's still not working. I've included my Widget Scaffold to show how I'm using the JSON to see if I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: Just to mention using your code in a separate project I can see it working with the print but I'm just not sure how to get it working for my situation

Comment: added a simple Widget to display the sorted list. BTW, I think your `List data` and `var response` aren't needed - remove them if that's correct.

Comment: Perfect thank you for your time and help on this. Now for the fun styling